# Convergence in metrisable topological spaces and Cauchy sequences

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, cauchy-sequences

Suppose I have a topological space $(F,\tau)$ which has some notion of convergence for elements in $F$ (denote this by e.g. $A_n \to_c A$ for $A_n, A \in F$). Furthermore, $(F,\tau)$ is metrisable and it is a Polish space (i.e. it is separable and there is a complete metric compatible with the topology).

If I show that $A_n-A_m \to_c \emptyset$ (convergence as I wrote above) as $n,m\to\infty$, does it follow that $A_n \to_c A$ for some $A$, i.e., does it follow that $A_n$ converges?
Or do I actually need to show that it's Cauchy in the complete metric that it possesses?

Comment: Do you mean $A_n, A \in F$ or $A_n, A \subseteq F$?

Comment: @AlexVong I do mean $\in$. I was thinking of $F$ as a space of closed convex subsets of some Banach space.

Comment: I see. I haven't studied functional analysis so I haven't seen that before.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. But when $\tau$ is a metizable topology we can define convergence of a sequence without mentioning any particular metric: The sequence $(x_n)_n$ converges to $x$ IFF for every nbhd $U$ of $x $, the set $\{n: x_n\not \in U\}$ is finite, IFF $\cap_{n=1}^{\infty } Cl(\{x_m:m>n\})=\{x\}.$.....( where $Cl(S$) denotes the closure of $S.$)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you not only a topological space, but also a vector space (or at least an Abelian group). If the complete metric $d$ you have is translation-invariant, i.e.,
$$d(x+z,y+z) = d(x,y)\,,$$
 then
$$d(A_n,A_m) = d(A_n-A_m,0)\,,$$
and so if $A_n-A_m \to 0$, then $(A_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence, hence convergent by the completeness of the metric.

If the complete metric is not translation-invariant, then you need to show that it is Cauchy by hand.